# Extracting characters from varchar strung in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

In one of the tables in my database, a column having details as nvarchar(50) is having values as abc$xyz. I want to extract everything after $ symbol in this column into another table.

Comment: What have you tried so far (please include the code in your question, not as a comment)?

Comment: Will there only be one instance/occurence of `$`?

Comment: Yes, there is only one instance of $ for sure

Comment: And, is there always going to be at least a $ in every string (and therefore EXACTLY one)?

Comment: Yes, one and only one $ is there

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTR and INSTR

```
select substr(MyString,instr(MyString,'$')+1) as NewString -- Use +1 to exclude the '$'
from MyTable
```

Comment: It worked.But what if I have to take the substring from second last occurrence of ','

Answer (score 0):

[REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302) will also work:

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('abc$xyz','.*\$') result FROM dual;

RESULT
------
xyz

SQL>
```

Comment: In most cases though, regexp should be used only when a simple solution with instr and substr does not exist.

Comment: I personally hate wading through nested SUBSTR/INSTR expressions.  I find them very difficult to read, and prefer REGEXP functions.  I understand that there may be a performance impact.

Comment: I agree, that is why I said "when a **simple** solution does not exist". In this case, the solution with instr and substr is so simple, it is hard to see how it would be any harder to read and maintain than a regexp_replace solution.

Answer (score 0):

If already using REGEX, I would go with **regexp_substr**.

```
select regexp_substr('abc$xyz','[^$]*$') result from dual;
```